# how to remove last character of text in div element

Tags: jquery, html, css, width

I create one div that put text in it. I want with jQuery calculate width of text in this div. and checked if width of text bigger of was parent element remove last character and check new width of text (without last character) and compare with width of parent element if bigger of parent element so continue this work (remove last character and check width) else if smaller of parent element put "**...**" in last text

this my code please guide me : http://jsfiddle.net/bw25w/

```
<div id="text-messege">
    <div>my name is mamal and I'm so alone....ohhhh my god help me!!! :( I love you guys.you are so good</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the div to not break the text and add `overflow:hidden` in CSS? Much easier...

Comment: Check out [jQuery.dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).

Comment: Wait, I don't understand. Are you trying to compare the length of characters inside divs or trying to compare the width of each div?

Comment: compare width of value in div with width of div(id="text-messege")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write this code and work it :D lol

```
$(function(){
    var widparent = ($('#text-messege').width())*1.5;
    var matn1 = $('#mamal').text();
    var spantest1 = '<span class="msg">' + matn1 + '</span>';
    $('body').append(spantest1);
    var widtext  = $('body .msg').width();
    $('body .msg').remove();

    if(widtext > widparent){
        var spanstr = null;
        var widstr = null;
        do{
            var str = matn1.substring(0, matn1.length-1);
            spanstr = '<span class="str">' + str + '</span>';
            $('body').append(spanstr);
            var widstr  = $('body .str').width();
            var valuestr = $('body .str').text();
            $('body .str').remove();
            matn1 = valuestr;
            //console.log(matn1);
            console.log(widstr,widparent);

        }while(widstr >= widparent);

        console.log(matn1);
        $('#mamal').text(matn1+'......');
    }



});
```

Answer (score 2):

Splice 1 symbol until container is taller (or wider)

```
var $container  = $("#text-messege")
 var $block  = $container.find("div");
 while($block.height()>$container.height()){
    $block.text($block.text().splice(-1))
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QMZUK/

Change cycle to

```
while($block.width()>$container.width())
```

if you have to verify width. 
Also pay attention to the css, if you have to compare sizes of parent and child, they should  NOT be the same sized (!!!).
GL

Anyways, I'd prefer using css solution like

```
 text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

read here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp
To apply css solution, child node with text should be INLINE; you can change div to span, or place css:

```
 display:inline;
```